# What can cause "The authenticated user may not have granted the app 69xxx995 write access to all of the children of file 0B6Bxxx",?

Tags: google-drive-api

My app creates a Drive folder, then uploads 100 files into it. 
Using my app, I can read, update and delete the files individually.

However if I try to delete the folder, I get "The authenticated user may not have granted the app 698xxx995 write access to all of the children of file 0B6B-xxx".

NB. The upload is done using a server, the delete is being done in Javascript.

I'm using the drive.file scope for my app, as recommended.

Any ideas?

Here are the steps ...

1. using the server, create a folder containing 100 files
2. try to delete the folder using the client, get the 403
3. using the same client, I delete each of the 100 files in the folder. no problem so now the folder is empty
4. try to delete the folder , get the 403 about the children

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a recreateable bug.
Using the code in [403 rate limit on insert sometimes succeeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578768/403-rate-limit-on-insert-sometimes-succeeds) ...

2. create a folder containing 97 files
3. delete it (POST to trash URL)
4. observe 200 response and the folder and files are gone
5. create a folder containing 100 files
6. delete it (POST to trash URL)
7. observe 403 The authenticated user may not have granted the app 698xxx995 write access to all of the children of file 0Bxxx

Post when deleting a folder with 97 files

```
Request URL:https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Bw3h_yCVtXbg/trash
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
```

Post when deleting a folder with 100 files

```
Request URL:https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0Bw3h_/trash
Request method:POST
Status Code:403 Forbidden
```

Comment: In order to eliminate any red herrings to do with client-id, I have verified that I get the same 403 forbidden if I delete the folder using the same server app that created it. So not only should there not be any error, the error that is thrown in misleading.

Answer (score 3):

To people with a similar error, maybe you can check your app's scope, change `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` to `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`.

This took me hours to find out what happened.

For detail: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes

Comment: sorry for the downvote, but this is a misleading answer. Most drive apps use drive.file scope for good reason. Changing it to drive (a) doesn't fix the bug that the question reports, and (b) significantly changes the marketability of the app since you are now asking the user to trust the app to see ALL of his drive files.

Comment: @pinoyyid Thank you for your comment,I agree with you. However,without `drive`,I can't delete folder created by my app.I'm using the latest node.js sdk,may be there is a bug? I can find another way to delete folder.

Comment: This is correct, even if it's bad for the publicity of the app. 
The official docs don't hint that the existing scope is not privileged enough, but for some applications that's exactly the case.

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth 2.0 credentials you are using for server and client side should be from the same API console project.

Comment: I've already checked that. Here is the sequence of events I've just done ...
using the server, create a folder containing 100 files
try to delete the folder using the client, get the 403
using the same client, I delete each of the 100 files in the folder. no problem
so now the folder is empty
try to delete it , get the 403

Comment: Just to add to the silliness, if instead of creating 100 files, I only create 50 files (of course using exactly the same code and procedure), I can happily delete the folder and its children.

Comment: More silliness. If I delete a random 25 files from the 100, AND empty the trash, then I can delete the folder.

Comment: Is there any progress with this bug?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar thing happen when trying to delete folders that contained other nested folders. After a bit of experimenting, I found that I was able to prevent the error by deleting all child folders before deleting the parent folder, rather than just trying to delete the single top-level parent folder.

I haven't had this error as of yet when deleting folders that contain only assorted files (text files, images, etc...). Of course, the error may just pop again in the future. I'll update this post if I start getting the error again...

Comment: Handling 500 Internal Service Errors is also important when doing this... missing one and not deleting a nested file will result in the 403 Error being thrown again.

Comment: I think I have a handle on this bug, but since Drive bugs aren't tracked anywhere, it's an educated guess. The issue is based on the number of children in any given folder. The Drive API architecture is that our apps speak to an API layer. This layer consumes our requests, and then submits them to Drive. What is happening (I think) is that the API layer is doing a recursive delete (I wish it wouldn't - but that's another story). Problem is, it's not following nextPageToken, so is only deleting 100 files. It then checks if the folder is empty and throws this exception if not.