# Google Drive API Error during deleting a sub folder with a file

Tags: google-drive-api

This is what I did. I have following hierarchy.

Folder A
Folder A\Folder B
Folder A \Folder C

Folder B has nothing in it
Folder C has a file in it which I uploaded through API

I have no problems deleting Folder B but when I delete Folder C. This is the error I get.

{"Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError\r\nThe authenticated user may not have granted the app 1068466789052 write access to all of the children of file 0B6SoKHS5o1IJV0lmV19qYkVWX3c [403]\r\nErrors [\r\n\tMessage[The authenticated user may not have granted the app 1068466789052 write access to all of the children of file 0B6SoKHS5o1IJV0lmV19qYkVWX3c] Location[Authorization - header] Reason[fileAccess] Domain[global]\r\n]\r\n"}

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you are using drive.file scope?

Three thoughts ...

1. Are you sure that the app that the created the file and folders is exactly the same app that is attempting the deletion?
2. If the answer to (1) is 'yes', then it's probably a bug. I get a whole bunch of issues with drive.file scope.
3. As a workaround, try changing to drive scope.

Another bug I've seen is where you try to delete a folder with more than 100 children. Your question says there is only one child file, but there could be more children in trash. The workaround for this bug is to do your own recursive deletion.
 See [What can cause "The authenticated user may not have granted the app 69xxx995 write access to all of the children of file 0B6Bxxx",?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575977/what-can-cause-the-authenticated-user-may-not-have-granted-the-app-69xxx995-wri)